# How to add component to XTemplate in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

How can I add a component to XTemplate in ExtJs? I need to add something like a button for instance.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With standard Ext JS `XTemplate` you can't use components as template values.

However you can use `CTemplate` extension which allows ExtJS components to be used as template values. **http://skirtlesden.com/ux/ctemplate**